# How to preserve type guard narrowing when using logical assignment?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, type-narrowing, typescript4.0, compound-operator

The following is an example that reproduces the problem:

```ts
type F = () => number;

type R = {
  [ x: string ]: R | F | undefined
}

const isFunc = <T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(maybe:unknown) : maybe is T => typeof maybe === "function";

const check = (i: R) => {

  let tmp:R = i;

  let curr = tmp["something"];

  if( isFunc<F>(curr) ) return;

  curr // R | undefined, expected

  tmp = curr || (curr = {}); //ok, expected

  tmp = curr ||= {}; //Index signature is missing in type 'F'

};
```

As you can see, after the type guard, `curr` is correctly narrowed to `R | undefined`. After that, I am reassigning `tmp` to `curr` and defaulting the latter to an empty object should it be missing.

Now, if the `A || A = B` approach is used, `curr` on the left side of the logical OR is properly narrowed to `R | undefined`. However, if I use the logical OR assignment to make the intent clearer, `curr` is inferred as `R | F | undefined`. This obviously results in an error, since `F` is not assignable to `R`.

The question is - what would be the reason for `curr` to be losing the narrowing in the second case?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UAUBKBA%20KA7ArgWwCMIAnAbgFgAoK0SKAJQSgG8qooBtKADwC4oAzsGIBLLAHMoAXX6MAPrCgKcWACYQAZmIiqqAXypUAxgHssQqCIEwVRpgB4AKlAjdgENQOQA6XwENicQF%20PywQDik0eExQkHQkPD8QIl4VAGssEwB3LDR%20ROToKyhnaKhaCBMNKAKiBHhEACINW2ARM0aKakpTc2AoIwALCCM0piQRWSjMVm72ABsIfuA8MF5GRBEutihF-qMcYmImFbAORoETPCXBsXFGqW3KdhENJEtrW3sYeIOjtDQxCWhywT3Yf2OAHpIQwlFAVOotFgdAAaFzcSBGdy6OblVZMCFKBRIQmIZh6FBgvFgAmHY5yORkvRPZlAA)

Comment: what is the equals sign for at the 21st line (`curr ||= {}`) ?

Comment: @Teneff, ehm, for the [logical OR assignment operator](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31011) (or [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#short-circuiting-assignment-operators)) - am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After submitting this as an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44553) in the source repository, the behavior has been confirmed to be a bug (more like a design limitation because no control-flow analysis is done when using logical assignment operators as opposed to short-circuiting assignment with logical operators).